# BTree map implementation by Google

Tags: c++, b-tree

I am trying to use the [Google's C++ BTree](https://code.google.com/p/cpp-btree/).

Code:

```
typedef btree_map<int, int> MyMap;
MyMap *obj_map = new MyMap;
obj_map->insert(make_pair(1,1));
obj_map->insert(make_pair(2,2));
obj_map->insert(make_pair(3,3));
obj_map->insert(make_pair(4,4));
obj_map->insert(make_pair(5,5));
obj_map->insert(make_pair(6,6));

MyMap::const_iterator lookup = obj_map->find(4);
printf("found %d", *lookup);
```

The first time I am running this it compiles with a warning but Eclipse prompts for an error:

```
ref_impl/../include/btree.h: In instantiation of ‘btree::btree_node<Params>::const_reference btree::btree_node<Params>::value(int) const [with Params = btree::btree_map_params<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >, 256>; btree::btree_node<Params>::const_reference = const std::pair<const int, int>&]’:
ref_impl/../include/btree.h:806:32:   required from ‘btree::btree_iterator<Node, Reference, Pointer>::reference btree::btree_iterator<Node, Reference, Pointer>::operator*() const [with Node = const btree::btree_node<btree::btree_map_params<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >, 256> >; Reference = const std::pair<const int, int>&; Pointer = const std::pair<const int, int>*; btree::btree_iterator<Node, Reference, Pointer>::reference = const std::pair<const int, int>&]’
ref_impl/core.cpp:404:22:   required from here
ref_impl/../include/btree.h:560:63: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
```

If I run the program again it runs and shows the correct result. The problem is that if I use the above implementation in a real program it does not present persistent results.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: `btree::btree_iterator::operator*()` returns `const std::pair<const int, int>&` in this case, not int.  I believe it "works" because you're getting "lucky".  Try setting the values to something other than the key value and see if it still "works" (also, try to avoid printf in C++ if possible).

Comment: My suggestions: 1) Don't use `printf` in C++ code. 2) Don't pass C++ classes through `...`.